# Descobrir se determinado controle é um botão

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tipagem, objetos

Possuo o seguinte código que serve para mudar a cor dos botões que estão em um painel:

```
private void mudaCorBotao(Button bt)
{
    foreach(Control b in Panel_esq.Controls)
    {
        if (/*[O que devo colocar aqui?]*/)
        {
            b.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
            b.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
    bt.BackColor = Color.White;
    bt.ForeColor = Color.Black
}
```

O que estou tentando fazer é: Quando o usuário clicar em qualquer botão desse painel, ele vai retornar todos os outros botões para a cor padrão e colocar o botão clicado em uma cor diferente. Mas não tenho a menor ideia de o que devo colocar dentro deste `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente:

```
private void mudaCorBotao(Button bt) {
    foreach(Control b in Panel_esq.Controls) {
        if (b is Button) {
            b.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
            b.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
    bt.BackColor = Color.White;
    bt.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ChangeColor2.cs).

Comment: Não sabia que existia esse "is" no if! Paguei muito pau já em situações que esse "is" ia ajudar muito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

[A resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199974/18246) está certa. Porém eu faria isso de uma forma mais simples, usando o método [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) do Linq.

Este método filtra os elementos da coleção com base no tipo especificado.

```
private void mudaCorBotao(Button bt)
{
    foreach(Control b in Panel_esq.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {           
        b.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
        b.ForeColor = Color.White;            
    }

    bt.BackColor = Color.White;
    bt.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado jbueno. Quero futuramente começar a dominar o Linq. Mas no momento estou sem tempo por conta da correria. Mas já é bom adquirir um conhecimento como o que você passou.